# How to structure Dynamic data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

Please help in structuring following type of data (example)- >

i have 1 table with list of all addresses of Restaurants.(1 database table for each City )

On querying each restaurant it returns a list of people who are in restaurant in format
{name ,timeduration,bill}
The number of rows returned in List is dynamic.

Now how can i store this data in mysql .

I would like to search by name etc so i cannot put full text in one column!

Comment: "1 database table for each City" - do not do this

Comment: MySQL is a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). I suggest you read up, [try something](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and repost.

Comment: i thought keeping different table would help in faster querying Or should i make one table with City Column. Will it run fast ? considering there are 30,000 restaurants.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary i have read that blog earlier also :) .  But here number of people is dynamic so I cannot have a people table and perform queries on this laarge table .

Comment: "within you, the Solution is." - yoda

Comment: Solution - One table would be fine. Look up `explain` to find out what your questions/updates are doing. Also read up about relational databases....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a structure to get you started:

```
CITY
----------
id
name

RESTAURANT
-----------
id
name
phone
address
city_id

PEOPLE
----------
id
name

ORDER
----------
id
restaurant_id
people_id
total (bill)
duration
date

RESTAURANT_ORDER
-----------------
id
restaurant_id
order_id
```

The restaurant_order table connects the restaurant with the people that ate there. Look here http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php for info how to retrieve stuff from it.